# Is there another solution than using cookie to pass request-response from back-end to front-end with express and react?

Tags: reactjs, express, request

I have the following Google Analytics API request I'm running after a Google Auth process. So far the only way I've found to pass the response to the front-end is to store the response in a cookie. Then I can easily read it with react. However, I don't really like this option. What would be my alternative? How could I pass the response otherwise?

```
   router.get(
        "/auth/google/callback",
        passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/error", session: false }),
        function(req, res) {
            var token = req.user.token;
        request('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=' + token,  
    function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(body)
      console.log(response)
              let views = []
       JSON.parse(body).items.forEach(view => {
                views.push({
                  name: view.webPropertyId + ' - ' + view.name + ' (' + view.websiteUrl + ')'
                })
              })
    res.cookie("data", views); 
    res.json(views)
    });
        }
    );
```

Comment: `res.send(views)` should do the trick. All you need to do is configure your front end to expect a JSON response from the server and parse it accordingly.

Comment: how do I configure the front-end? with fetch or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the frontend, make a call to your backend using something like fetch and then parse the response in JSON. It might look something like this:

```
fetch('/auth/google/callback',
  { 
   method: 'GET',
   credentials: 'same-origin'
  })
.then(response => response.json());
```

And on the backend, just use `res.send(views)` where views is an object.

You may have to add additional headers for auth (as it seems like you're looking for a token in your api call), but that should just be a matter of adding it in to the options object.

Comment: so it means that I need to pass the token from the back-end to the front-end at some point or? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: If you're getting the token on the client and then requesting your server to use that token to get data, then yes you'll need to pass it to the backend. Normally, this is done via an authorization header or something similar. If, on the other hand, the token is simply your apps unique identifier to the API it's calling and the client doesn't have/need access to it, then don't worry about it.

Comment: Looking at your code a little closer it looks like the token is supplied by the passport.authenticate function. I'm not familiar with passport myself, so I'm not sure if this is supplied as a cookie to passport or as a header. How are you currently making this request to your backend?

Comment: yes. everything happens on the back-end. That also where I'm confused I think. I don't want to send the token to the front-end to send it back to the back-end.

Comment: Then ignore that part. The comment was made as a "if you need it, here's how you do it" sort of thing.